# Multiple OR conditions within DO IF framework evaluating as SYSMIS

Tags: spss

I'm trying to create a new variable that generates a "1" for a case if that case selected "1" in any variable in a series of other variables. However, trying the below code evaluates every case to a SYSMIS, even though some respondents have selected "1" in a variable in the reference series of variables.

I tried using a DO IF structure with two ELSE IF's, but no joy.

Here's what I tried so far (the variables in the reference series can take on a "1" (the desired value) a "0", or a "998"):

```
*ELA dichotomous*

DO IF (w1t_gr1.2=1 OR
           w1t_gr2.2=1 OR
           w1t_gr3.2=1 OR
           w1t_gr3.2=1 OR
           w1t_gr4.2=1 OR
           w1t_gr5.2=1 OR
           w1t_gr6.2=1 OR
           w1t_gr7.2=1 OR
           w1t_gr8.2=1).
COMPUTE rw1t_ela=1.
ELSE IF (w1t_gr1.2=0 OR
           w1t_gr2.2=0 OR
           w1t_gr3.2=0 OR
           w1t_gr3.2=0 OR
           w1t_gr4.2=0 OR
           w1t_gr5.2=0 OR
           w1t_gr6.2=0 OR
           w1t_gr7.2=0 OR
           w1t_gr8.2=0).
COMPUTE rw1t_ela=0.
ELSE IF (w1t_gr1.2=998 OR
           w1t_gr2.2=998 OR
           w1t_gr3.2=998 OR
           w1t_gr3.2=998 OR
           w1t_gr4.2=998 OR
           w1t_gr5.2=998 OR
           w1t_gr6.2=998 OR
           w1t_gr7.2=998 OR
           w1t_gr8.2=998).
COMPUTE rw1t_art=0.
ELSE.
COMPUTE rw1t_art=0.
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

I expected this to give a "1" for anyone who selected a "1" in any of the reference series of variables (e.g., in w1t_gr3.2), but every case evaluates to SYSMIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you posted creates two variables, `rw1t_ela` should actually work like you described, and the second variable `rw1t_art` should be missing for all cases where any of the eight original variables contains 0 or 1.
If you replace `rw1t_art` with `rw1t_ela` in your syntax, it should work well.

That being said, there is a more efficient way to do what you need:
The following code will give you a value of 1 in `rw1t_ela` only when one of the other variables contains 1, and 0 in all other cases:

```
compute rw1t_ela=any(1, w1t_gr1.2, w1t_gr2.2, w1t_gr3.2, w1t_gr4.2, 
                        w1t_gr5.2, w1t_gr6.2, w1t_gr7.2, w1t_gr8.2).
```